# Service Executing SMS at Incorrect Intervals

Tags: java, android, service, time, android-alarms

I've written an application which checks a user's mobile and wifi data usage and sends to VIA sms - however the SMS message is being sent every 15 seconds (as the service repeats) instead of checking to ensure it hasn't been executed in the last 30 days.

I've implemented some code which is supposed to prevent the service from sending a SMS unless 30 days has elapsed - but it does not seem to be working - it is sending the SMS every 15 seconds (which is not desired.)

```
// check to ensure proper time has elapsed

        long days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
        long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30) {


// send traffic info via sms & save the current time


    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager
                .sendTextMessage("7862611848", null, info, null, null);
        String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
        editor.commit();
```

// Full Source Code:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = "DataCountService";
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final long PERIOD = 1000 * 15; // x min
    private final long DELAY_INTERVAL = 0; // x Seconds

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
            if (text.contains("//USR;1")) {

                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);

                // check to ensure proper time has elapsed
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
                long days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30) {

                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                                Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }

                    String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
                } else if

                (text.contains("//USR;0")) {
                    stopSelf();

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                    // character
                } else {

                    Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

                }
            }
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
        return startId;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    /*
     * @Override public void onCreate() extends PhoneStateListener {
     * 
     * 
     * EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener(); TelephonyManager
     * mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     * mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); }
     */

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // set number of calls to 1 in SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences callpref = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
            Editor callprefeditor = callpref.edit();
            callprefeditor.putString("calls", "1");
            callprefeditor.commit();

        }

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "DataCountService", 0);

        if (pref.getString("calls", "1") == "1") {

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
            if (text.contains("USI;1;")) {

                // String swappedMdn(Context ctx){
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
                String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();
                // Insure MDN is 10 characters
                if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
                    mdn = "0000000000";
                // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
                if (mdn.length() > 10)
                    mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
                char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
                char digit;
                for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length()) % 2; index += 2) {
                    digit = data[index];
                    data[index] = data[index + 1];
                    data[index + 1] = digit;
                }
                return;
            }

            // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
            double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
            double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                    + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
            totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
            totalBytes /= 1000000;
            mobileBytes /= 1000000;
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
            String tag = ";";
            String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
            String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
            String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag, mobileStr,
                    totalStr);

            // check to ensure proper time has elapsed
            long days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
            long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30) {

                // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager
                        .sendTextMessage("7865555555", null, info, null, null);
                String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
                editor.commit();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
            } else if

            (text.contains("USI;1;")) {
                stopSelf();

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                // character
            } else {

                Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

            }

        }

    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);

                // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences

                SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
                Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                editor.putString("last_month", info);
                editor.commit();

                // check to ensure proper time has elapsed
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
                long days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30) {

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage)
                    // and
                    // save the current time
                    String sms = "";

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                                Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                    }

                }
            }
        }, DELAY_INTERVAL, PERIOD);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

### Edit #1

SOURCE:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = "DataCountService";
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final long PERIOD = 1000 * 15; // x min
    private final long DELAY_INTERVAL = 0; // x Seconds

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
            if (text.contains("//USR;1")) {

                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);

                // check to ensure proper time has elapsed
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
                 long days_30 = 1000; // * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                 long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
                 if(System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30){

                // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                            Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String shortCode = settings.getString(
                            Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                            Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                            null);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    editor.commit();

                } else {
                    SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE,
                            null, info, null, null);
                }

                String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
            } else if

            (text.contains("//USR;0")) {
                stopSelf();

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                // character
            } else {

                Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
        return startId;

     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    /*
     * @Override public void onCreate() extends PhoneStateListener {
     * 
     * 
     * EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener(); TelephonyManager
     * mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     * mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); }
     */

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // set number of calls to 1 in SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences callpref = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
            Editor callprefeditor = callpref.edit();
            callprefeditor.putString("calls", "1");
            callprefeditor.commit();


        }

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "DataCountService", 0);

        if (pref.getString("calls", "1") == "1") {

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
            if (text.contains("USI;1;")) {




        //      String swappedMdn(Context ctx){ 
                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    //Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
                    String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();
                    //Insure MDN is 10 characters
                    if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null) mdn ="0000000000";
                    //Extract last 10 digits of MDN
                    if (mdn.length() > 10) mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length()); 
                    char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
                    char digit;
                    for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length())%2; index+=2){
                        digit = data[index];
                        data[index] = data[index+1];
                        data[index+1] = digit;
                    }
                    return; 
                }



                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);

                // check to ensure proper time has elapsed
                 long days_30 = 1000;// * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                 long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
                 if(System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30){

                // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager
                        .sendTextMessage("7862611848", null, info, null, null);
                String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
                editor.commit();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
            } else if

            (text.contains("USI;1;")) {
                stopSelf();

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                // character
            } else {

                Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

            }

        }

    }


    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);

                // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences

                SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
                Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                editor.putString("last_month", info);
                editor.commit();

                // check to ensure proper time has elapsed
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
                 long days_30 = 1000; // * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                 long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
                 if(System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30){

                // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage) and
                // save the current time
                String sms = "";

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                            Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String shortCode = settings.getString(
                            Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                            Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                            sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null, null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    editor.commit();
                } else {

                    SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE,
                            null, sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                            null);
                    editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    editor.commit();
                }

            }
            }}, DELAY_INTERVAL, PERIOD);
        }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timerTask shoots every 15 secs ... Are you sure that the preferences store and return the correct value? Seems to me your condition `System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30` will always be true.

Inside the timertask you actually do not set "oldTime" after having sent the SMS in the non-"Config.DEVELOPMENT" branch.

You should get rid of code duplication and make sure which code is actually executed :

- Use (private) methods.
- Use Logging.

With cleaner code you save a lot of sweat.

Comment: Isn't it being set within the timerTask by using the line:


editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: I changed it to include the value... but it's still not functioning.

Comment: @NoobDev954 Can you update the code in your question, please?

Comment: You could as well have moved it behind the if/else block. So it gets executed independently of "Config.Development" ...

Comment: @NoobDev954 Can you [log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) what value you are getting for oldValue from sharedPrefs ? `long days_30 = 1000; // * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;` Is this on purpose? That's one second. You can use [TimeUnit](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html).

Comment: Yes it is on purpose - It was just for testing purposes to see if the timer was working (I figured I'd make it as short as possible to ensure it was working - but it isn't)

Comment: BTW - I just noticed my long days_30 is resulting in a negative number